# Subtract Two Values from Different Table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to subtract values from payment table and order1 table. 
This is the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

How can I subtract two values from different table?

The operation should be like this:

total (from order1 table) = total(from order1 table) - amount (from payment table)

```
$amount=$_POST['amount']; //payment table
//code inserting values in payment table    

//code for updating order1 table 
mysql_query("UPDATE order1 
         SET total=(SELECT total from order_details 
                    WHERE order_id='$order_id')- $amount
         WHERE order_id= '$order_id'
        ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: If there are several order_details rows for an order_id, which total value do you want to store in order1?

Comment: I want to update the total value from order1 after adding the payment made: total ( from order1) = total (from order1) - amount (from payment table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
     UPDATE order1 as o
     join order_details as d on o.order_id=d.order_id and o.order_id='$order_id'
     set o.total=d.total - $amount
```